# JMS Rollback & redelivery not honoring the RedeliveryDelay configuration

Tags: spring, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I would like to have my Camel routes transactional with ActiveMQ. Rollback and maximum re-deliveries work fine, but not re-delivery delay, which should be incremental.

For example, when I failed to process message (raising an exception), it's redelivered 3 times (as expected), but with **no time** between it (which is not).

My Spring configuration:

```
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="fr.dush.poc.springplaceholder"/>

<spring:camelContext>
    <spring:package>fr.dush.poc.springplaceholder.routes</spring:package>
    <spring:contextScan/>
</spring:camelContext>

<bean id="jmsTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.JmsTransactionManager">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="PROPAGATION_REQUIRED" class="org.apache.camel.spring.spi.SpringTransactionPolicy">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="jmsTransactionManager"/>
</bean>
<bean id="PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW" class="org.apache.camel.spring.spi.SpringTransactionPolicy">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="jmsTransactionManager"/>
    <property name="propagationBehaviorName" value="PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW"/>
</bean>
```

Spring configuration continue in configuration bean:

```
@Component
public class CamelFactories {

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CamelFactories.class);

public static final int REDELIVERY_DELAY = 1000;
public static final int BACK_OFF_MULTIPLIER = 2;
public static final int HOUR = 3600000;
public static final int MAXIMUM_REDELIVERY_DELAY = 2 * HOUR;
public static final int MAXIMUM_REDELIVERIES = 3;

@Bean(name = "jmsConnectionFactory")
public ActiveMQConnectionFactory createFactory() {
    ActiveMQConnectionFactory factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
    factory.setBrokerURL("tcp://localhost:61616");

    RedeliveryPolicy policy = new RedeliveryPolicy() {

        @Override
        public long getNextRedeliveryDelay(long previousDelay) {
            long nextDelay = super.getNextRedeliveryDelay(previousDelay);
            LOGGER.warn("Previous delay={} ; This delay={} ", previousDelay, nextDelay);
            return nextDelay;
        }
    };
    policy.setMaximumRedeliveries(MAXIMUM_REDELIVERIES);

    policy.setRedeliveryDelay(REDELIVERY_DELAY);
    policy.setBackOffMultiplier(BACK_OFF_MULTIPLIER);
    policy.setUseExponentialBackOff(true);
    policy.setMaximumRedeliveryDelay(MAXIMUM_REDELIVERY_DELAY);

    factory.setRedeliveryPolicy(policy);

    return factory;
}

@Bean(name = "activemq")
public JmsComponent createJmsComponent(JmsTransactionManager transactionManager,
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {

    ActiveMQComponent component = new ActiveMQComponent();
    component.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
    component.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    component.setTransacted(true);

    return component;
}
```

My route is quite simple:

```
public class CamelRouteBuilder extends SpringRouteBuilder {

  @Override
  public void configure() throws Exception {

    Policy required = getApplicationContext().getBean("PROPAGATION_REQUIRED",
            SpringTransactionPolicy.class);

    from("activemq:queue:foo.bar")
            .transacted()
            .policy(required)

            .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "fr.dush.poc", "Receive message: ${body}")
            .beanRef("serviceBean") // throw an exception
            .to("mock:routeEnd");
  }
}
```

And in my logs, I have this, 3 times with previous delay=0:

```
CamelFactories:36 - Previous delay=0 ; This delay=1000
```

It seems I'm not alone to have this issue, but I still didn't find solution...

Thanks,

-Dush

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possibly resolved by setting cacheLevelName=CACHE_CONSUMER on the ActiveMQComponent. I had the same symptoms & this resolved it for me. On a related note, I also get out of order delivery of messages with a transacted component, unless I use CACHE_CONSUMER.

Comment: This should be the correct answer. With consumer-level retry policies, it is important that Camel does not recreate the consumer after every failed processing attempt. Else, when consumers get created new for every received message, no state about previous attempts is retained.

Answer (score 0):

I still didn't find solution. But I found an alternative: retry API from CAMEL itself.

Configuration is very similar. Spring config example:

```
<redeliveryPolicyProfile id="infiniteRedeliveryPolicy" 
                         asyncDelayedRedelivery="true"
                         redeliveryDelay="${camel.redelivery_delay}"
                         maximumRedeliveryDelay="${camel.maximum_redelivery_delay}"
                         maximumRedeliveries="${camel.infinite_redelivery}"
                         backOffMultiplier="${camel.back_off_multiplier}"
                         useExponentialBackOff="true"/>

<routeContext>
  <route>
    <!-- ... -->

    <!-- Define behaviour in case of technical error -->
    <onException redeliveryPolicyRef="infiniteRedeliveryPolicy">
       <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
       <handled>
           <constant>false</constant>
       </handled>

       <log message="Message can't be processed for now. I'll retry later!" />
    </onException>
  </route>
</routeContext>
```

Consumers should be **transactional** if you want to keep not processed messages in the ActiveMQ queue, even if you shut down application.

Comment: Please note that the redelivery policy on an onException or errorHandler is NOT the same as a redelivery policy at connection factory level. onException or errorHandler cause a retry at the point of failure, with the message as is. Also, the transaction would not roll back between retries but would remain open for the entire time that the onException or errorHandler attempts to retry.